# XSLT counting child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I rarely use XLST and get confusing results when I try to count child nodes in a parent node.

**Edit:**

The XML is structured as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Response>
  <result>
    <name>Someone</name>
    **<rating>4.5</rating>**
    <review>
      <text>Some review.</text>
    </review>
    <review>
      <text>Another review.</text>
    </review>
  </result>
  <result>
    <name>Another one</name>
    **<rating>2</rating>**
    <review>
      <text>Blah, grieve, blah.</text>
    </review>
    <review>
      <text>Blah, grrrrr, blah.</text>
    </review>
    <review>
      <text>Blah, good grrrrr, blah.</text>
    </review>
  </result>
  ...
  ...
</Response>
```

The template (simplified) is as follows:

```
**<body>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
</body>**

<xsl:template match="Response/result">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="name">
      <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </div>
    <xsl:if test="rating">
        <span class="review-count">
          **(<xsl:value-of select="count(review)"/>)**
        </span>
    </xsl:if>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

I do not get the correct child node count from this approach. In addition to the `count(review)`, I tried `count(descendant::review)` and several xPath variations. I know I'm missing something simple - but what?

Comment: What are you getting and what are you expecting?  Also, your xml input doesn't have any `rating` elements so your `count()` won't get executed.

Comment: Also, you didn't remove any `xsl:for-each` (which would change context) when simplifying your xsl template did you?

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I amended the "rating" omission and clarified the code a bit. The only code I removed was working correctly - no xsl:for-each anywhere.

Comment: What processor are you using? Using saxon and your xml/xsl:template I correctly get `**(2)**` for the first result and `**(3)**` for the second result.

Comment: You are right Daniel, it turns out I need help in counting on my fingers - the results are correct. Thanks for your effort and correct assessment.

Comment: Regarding not using XSLT frequently; I feel your pain.   Every time I have to do something in XSLT I wind up here at StackOverflow.  :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:if test="rating">
>     <span class="review-count">
>       **(<xsl:value-of select="count(review)"/>)**
>     </span>
> </xsl:if>
> ```

This will never generate even a single character, because there is no `rating` element in the provided XML document. In case you remove the above conditional instruction, then the result contains the wanted count values.

If you indeed have `rating` child for at least some `review` elements (but failed to show this to us), then you probably also didn't show other important parts of the XML document -- such as a default namespace.

**Update**:

The OP has provided a more precise XML document, that contains `rating` elements.

**I can't repro the problem**.

**This XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Response/result">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </div>
        <xsl:if test="rating">
            <span class="review-count">
              **(<xsl:value-of select="count(review)"/>)**
            </span>
        </xsl:if>
      </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Response>
  <result>
    <name>Someone</name>
      <rating>4.5</rating>
    <review>
      <text>Some review.</text>
    </review>
    <review>
      <text>Another review.</text>
    </review>
  </result>
  <result>
    <name>Another one</name>
      <rating>2</rating>
    <review>
      <text>Blah, grieve, blah.</text>
    </review>
    <review>
      <text>Blah, grrrrr, blah.</text>
    </review>
    <review>
      <text>Blah, good grrrrr, blah.</text>
    </review>
  </result>
  ...
  ...
</Response>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
  <div class="item">
   <div class="name">Someone</div>
   <span class="review-count">
              **(2)**
            </span>
</div>

<div class="item">
   <div class="name">Another one</div>
   <span class="review-count">
              **(3)**
            </span>
</div>
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: Yes, I guess I got a little delete happy with the XML file. I have edited the question and highlighted the changes. Although you are quite correct that I omitted the "rating". I am able to access all other XML elements without issues, so can this be a namespace problem? I hope the changes I made clarify the problem and I thank you for your answer.

Comment: @rontornambe, Please, see the updated answer. I couldn't repro the reported problem. The reason obviously is in the XSLT code that you havent shown to us.

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful to know that what is shown seems okay. I will study the rest of the code in the morning when I have a fresh eye and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @rontornambe, Goodnight :)

Comment: Hey Dmitre, just in case you are still curious, I posted the complete xml/xsl here: http://top-50.bunkerhill.com/mainpage.xml, http://top-50.bunkerhill.com/mainpage.xslt

Comment: @rontornambe, Thanks, but the XML is too-big. I will be going to bed shortly, and in case you provide (here in the question) a small XML document, I could have a look at it in the morning.

Comment: Turns out that I just shouldn't count that late in the evening. The results I am getting are indeed correct. (I am about to try implement one of your posts on sorting, so TIA!)